# Deleting or get rid of complete array which doesnt have all desired items in an array

Tags: javascript, html

delete array which doesnt have "category" field

req:wanted to get rid of obj[0] & obj[2] as they doesn't hav category field...

for example:

js data:

```
var obj=[

{"email":"rteh@tm.com","event":"open"},
{"ip":"24.38.43.233","email":"rtehrani@tmcnet.com","category":["webinar"]},
{"email":"glin@gl.com","event":"open"},
{"ip":"24.98.43.230","email":"glin@gl.com","category":["webinar"]},
{"ip":"24.77.55.931","email":"klen@gmail.com","category":["webinar"]},
{"ip":"44.67.85.456","email":"bryan@gmail.com","category":["webinar"]}

];
```

expected o/p:

var obj=[

```
{"ip":"24.38.43.233","email":"rtehrani@tmcnet.com","category":["webinar"]},
{"ip":"24.98.43.230","email":"glin@gl.com","category":["webinar"]},
{"ip":"24.77.55.931","email":"klen@gmail.com","category":["webinar"]},
{"ip":"44.67.85.456","email":"bryan@gmail.com","category":["webinar"]}
```

];

question is edited...for simple understanding,
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but I'm assuming that you want to get rid of all objects that don't have a `category` property. This snippet would do it.

```js
var obj=[
  {"email":"rteh@tm.com","event":"open"},
  {"ip":"24.38.43.233","email":"rtehrani@tmcnet.com","category":["webinar"]},
  {"email":"glin@gl.com","event":"open"},
  {"ip":"24.38.43.230","email":"glin@gl.com","category":["webinar"]}
];

var result = obj.filter(participation => participation.hasOwnProperty('category'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply,have tried your code but it results the arrays which doesnt have "category" field, exactly opposite to my requirement...i need only arrays which have category....pls check and update ...

Comment: @jesseoneshmark check the updated answer, I only negated the filter condition.